# Spotify long term login with Android SDK

Tags: android, authorization, spotify

I'm looking forward to implement an app which connects to Spotify. To use Spotify services, I need a token, which I can get with the Spotify SDK, however this token is intended for quick expiring not for long term use. In the web API I can make calls from within my server to get new access tokens via refresh_token. I know this must be done in a call server to server. But, I don't know how should I manage the info provided by the Android Spotify SDK to get the refresh_token from the server. I don't even know if this can be achieved via the Spotify SDK or will I have to implement the whole authorization. I've searched info in the web but I can't find info related to this subject. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I have developed an app which also uses Spotify's services. Since I wanted to query audio features of a song, I had to use Spotify's Web API instead as Spotify's Android SDK hasn't provided such thing yet. When I implemented the app I didn't think about it too much so every time when I need to do queries I'd get the access token again. You can get the token using the following code, inside the json string also comes with a expires_in property that tells you how many seconds the token will expire, therefore it should be easy to achieve what you want with some slight modification.

```
private String getAccessTokenFromJsonStr(String spotifyJsonStr) throws JSONException {
    final String OWM_ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";
    String accessToken;

    try {
        JSONObject spotifyJson = new JSONObject(spotifyJsonStr);
        accessToken = spotifyJson.getString(OWM_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return accessToken;
}

private String getSpotifyAccessToken(){
    String response;
    String accessToken;
    try {
        String serviceURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
        URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL);

        HttpsURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();

        String userCredentials = "YOUR_USER_CREDENTIALS:YOUR_USER_CREDENTIALS";
        int flags = Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE;
        byte[] encodedString = Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes(), flags);
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(encodedString);
        myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

        myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        System.setProperty("http.agent", "");

        HashMap postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        postDataParams.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        OutputStream os = myURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        response = "";
        int responseCode=myURLConnection.getResponseCode();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "response code is " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";
            String errLine;
            String errResponse = "";
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getErrorStream()));
            while ((errLine=br.readLine()) != null) {
                errResponse += errLine;
            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error response is " + errResponse);

        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "response is " + response);


    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String accessTokenJsonStr = response.toString();
    try {
        accessToken = getAccessTokenFromJsonStr(accessTokenJsonStr);
        return accessToken;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

[Authorization-guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you need a refresh token (the token provided by SDK lasts for one hour, and then you have to request another one) you need to use the web api to fetch this token. In this case you would not use the SDK for any part of the authentication process. Technically you don't have to use a server↔server component for the passing secret to Spotify server auth step, it's just best practice (security wise) to avoid hard coding the secret into your app, but technically there is nothing preventing you from doing all the [authentication steps](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) app↔spotify server utilizing the pertinent web api calls.

Comment: My issue is that requesting another token cannot be done with the Android SDK (or if it can be done, I don't know how). To get another token I must use the activity the SDK provides. I cannot do it in the background, which is my goal. My current solution is not using the SDK for auth at all and implement it via the web API.

Comment: You can get a new token, yes through their activity, or webview. It's the same action intent call just handling on their side (webview-activity or their apps activity) depends on wether the Spotify app is installed on the device. However, there shouldn't be a problem using their intent/activity, as after you have logged in once the credentials are cached the user is no longer presented with the login activity. Just a spinner for half a second and then you get a new token. No extra prompts as long as you're not asking for any extra permissions than you did on the previous login call.

Comment: This works if the user has their screen on. I've tried calling the Activity in the background and it's not working for me.

Comment: Yes in this case you have to use the web API, unfortunately. Until they add better support to the SDK.